# Does WordPress allow me to mark posts as private?

Tags: wordpress, privacy, cms, access-control

Suppose I want to start a blog.  I would like the "professional" stuff to be public, but the "personal" stuff should only be accessible to friends and family (i.e., accessible only to those users to which I give permission).  Can WordPress do this?

Comment: Off topic (it wouldn't have been if you ask for a service which allows you to blog, a software you install yourself on your server is).

Comment: @neo: That's an interesting take on this question.  Are CMS not generally web apps?  Is the question not appropriate because I'm asking about back-end administration vs. front-end usage?

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase and to make it a bit more specific, I have blog (wordpress, blogger, etc) how can I make it accessible only to those users to which I give permission. I do not see it as off topic as an end user can be a wordpress.com user. `Is the question not appropriate because I'm asking about back-end administration vs. front-end usage? ` Yes it is not appropriate based on the definition of this site from area51. If it is about privacy in posting similar to privacy in posting to say Facebook I would say in that case this question is appropriate.

Comment: Seems to me this would be better posted in Webmasters when it goes public.

Comment: You guys are right.  This wasn't a good question.  Since I can't delete it, I rewrote to better fit the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) for sure. See [Set blog content visibility (Classic Editor)](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/content-visibility-classic-editor/):

> Content visibility is about controlling who can see your blog content. WordPress allows you to control the visibility of your posts and Pages on an individual basis. By default, all posts and Pages are visible.
>
> There are several ways to set the visibility for your blog content. You can set it on a per post/Page basis for public, private, or Password Protected, or make the entire blog private and Password Protected through the use of WordPress Plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Posterous](http://posterous.com/) in this way; I have a public blog and a private blog, and I can mark posts on the public blog as private...